# How to capture return value for Event handler?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Environment: MS SQL Server,  EF, WCF-RIA-Service, Sliverlight

try to define an event for async call complete event like:

```
public event EventHandler<int> MySaveComplete;
```

the event for this is to call a SP in DB and return a ID value(int).

but got error message as when try to compile the code:

> The type 'int' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEventArgs' in the
>   generic type or method 'System.EventHandler'. There is no
>   boxing conversion from 'int' to 'System.EventArgs'

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Using an event is not indicated here, use a callback method instead.  Note the AsyncCallback argument in the SqlCommand.BeginExecuteXxx methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EventHandler<T>` requires generic argument to be of type `EventArgs` (i.e. one inherited from it). So, you should create your own class:

```
public class MySaveCompleteEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MySaveCompleteEventArgs(int id)
    {
       ID = id;
    }

    public int ID { get; private set; }
}
```

And use it as `EventHandler<T>` argument:

```
public event EventHandler<MySaveCompleteEventArgs> MySaveComplete;
```

Event raising:

```
protected void OnMySaveComplete(int id)
{
    if (MySaveComplete == null)
        return;

    MySaveComplete(this, new MySaveCompleteEventArgs(id));
}
```

---

You can use also `Action<int>` delegate as event type.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. What's the solution for this case? I want to get the return value in complete event.